# Llenar comboBox con datos de base de datos en SQLite

Tags: java

Necesito que un comboBox se llene con datos de la columna "Producto", de tal manera que cada que agregue productos, el comboBox se actualice automáticamente. En la web solamente hay tutoriales con MySQL y yo lo necesito con SQLite, creo que la sintaxis es un poco diferente entre ambos y no me funciona. Es en Java. Por favor y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos primero deberías tener tu conexión algo así:

```
private Connection connect() {
    // SQLite conexion
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C://mi/db/test.db";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
```

con dicha conexión haremos una consulta:

```
  String sql = "SELECT id, nombre FROM productos";
  try (Connection conn = this.connect();
         Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){

        //recorriendo el result
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") +  "\t" + 
                               rs.getString("nombre") + "\t");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

bien ya con esto puedes llenar tu DropDown espero te sirva y suerte, intentalo y cuando ya tengas un error postea tu pregunta con tu código y error obtenido.

mas sobre la conexión: [JDBC SQLITE](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/)